# Probability of getting an even distribution of answers on a multiple choice test.

Tags: probability, statistics, word-problem

What is the likelihood of having an even distribution of answers (i.e. 2 A's, 2 B's, 2 C's, and 2 D's) across eight multiple choice questions with four possible answers each?

My friend and I tried doing this in Python 3 because neither of us have taken Statistics yet and we got different answers. I have a feeling my answer is slightly off: $\frac{2520}{65536}$ or $3.84521484375$%.

What I want to know is how I would do this mathematically?

Comment: Your answer is correct - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution.

Comment: Essentially - it is $\binom{8}{2 \ 2 \ 2 \ 2} (1/4)^8$

Comment: Thanks for the help!